# Form Submit doesn't return data to server in Firefox, but ok in Explorer

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

Here is the code. Functionally it works fine, but won't collect the data when firefox used.

Javascript

```
var redirectPage = "rsvp.html"; //CHANGE redirected page here.


function submitform() {
    document.bandform.submit(); //CHANGE name of form here
    RedirectWithFormValues();
}

function RedirectWithFormValues() {
    var band = GetRadioValue("nameband"); //CHANGE name of variable here
    window.location = redirectPage + "?band=" + band; //CHANGE name of new variable here
}

function GetRadioValue(rdName) {
    var rd = document.getElementsByName(rdName);
    for (var i = 0; i < rd.length; i++) {
        if (rd[i].checked) {
            return rd[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Markup

```
<form action="" method="post" name="bandform">  
    <input name="nameband" type="radio" value="Noon - 1pm" checked="checked" class="radio1">
    <input name="nameband" type="radio" value="5pm - 6pm" class="radio2">
    <input type="button" value="" class="button1" name="" onclick="javascript:submitform();">  
< /form>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not going to work in most browsers:

```
function submitform() {
    document.bandform.submit(); //CHANGE name of form here
    RedirectWithFormValues();
}
```

What you ought to do is something like this with jQuery:

```
$('#bandform').ajaxForm({
    success: RedirectWithFormValues
});
```

That will do an AJAX submit on the form, and when complete, call the RedirectWithFormValues function.

Comment: Unfortunately, the AJAX submit is a little beyond me. I will test though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why not just set the redirectPage value (with band selection) to the form's action element, and then just let the form submit (return true from submitForm()) instead of doing the redirect?

```
function submitform() {
    setFormAction();
    return true;
}

function setFormAction() {
    var band = GetRadioValue("nameband");
    var redirectUrl = redirectPage + "?band=" + band;
    document.getElementById('bandform').action = redirectUrl;
}

function GetRadioValue(rdName) {
    var rd = document.getElementsByName(rdName);
    for (var i = 0; i < rd.length; i++) {
        if (rd[i].checked) {
            return rd[i].value;
        }
    }
}

<form action="" method="post" id="bandform" name="bandform">  
    <input name="nameband" type="radio" value="Noon - 1pm" checked="checked" class="radio1">
    <input name="nameband" type="radio" value="5pm - 6pm" class="radio2">
    <input type="submit" name="" onClick="submitform()" value="Submit" />
< /form>
```

Comment: woops!  sorry, relealized that should be a submit button, not an input button..making the change...*changed*

Answer (score 0):

Instead try the code below,

Aspx section,

```
        <form name='bandform' method='post' action='' onsubmit='return submitform();'>
            <input type='submit' value=' Send Message ' /> 
        </form>
```

Javascript Section,

```
       function submitform() {

       document.bandform.submit(); 
       RedirectWithFormValues();

       return true;
       }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks! I did a preliminary test, and it didn't immediately function correctly. I will try again. Our challenge is that we are using a service (FUSION PRO LINKS) which does the hosting and purl re-routing. I will try again.